# tcp read() immediately after accept()

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp

If I call send() immediately after synchronous connect() returns on the client side, is it reasonable to expect that calling read() immediately after accept() on the server side will return the first segment of data?  I.e., will a client receiving the SYN-ACK typically wait a bit to see whether there is any payload to include on the ACK completing the 3-way handshake?

The first message in my protocol will include an authentication token (< 500 bytes), so was thinking it would be handy to synchronously read() and validate immediately after accept(), and close the socket if not valid.  Otherwise, it seems like I need to have some state tied up waiting for asynchronous time out.  I will be dealing with a limited set of common client platforms, so not concerned about theoretical possibilities across all TCP implementation.

Comment: I can't quite understand what you're asking. You ask if "calling `read()` immediately after `accept()` on the server side will return the first segment of data", but what else could it possibly do?!

Comment: Yes. The Nagle algorithm will try to piggyback the ACK onto the next data segment.

Comment: David, I forgot to mention the socket is nonblocking, so will generate EAGAIN error if the 1st segment has not arrived.

Comment: EJP, what I see with tcpdump on OSX (loopback address) is ->SYN,<-SYN-ACK,->ACK,<-ACK,->first data segment.  Seems to be an unnecessary pair of ACKS.

Comment: It will try. It may not happen that way, for timing and othe reasons. No idea what the extra ACK is about. Does it have a different sequence number from the previous one in the same direction?

Comment: I tossed the logs, but it might be the default tcp configuration on the loopback being peculiar, e.g., no Nagle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Even if you could rely on well-behaved clients, in network problems it is almost *never* safe to rely on anything happening reliably like that.

Also, when you're using unencrypted data, all sorts of intermediate routers will think its their business to muck with the data.

With UDP the problem is actually simpler, though obviously you have to implement your own reliability and congestion-control algorithms.

Comment: I agree, if the ACK goes out in a separate packet, all bets are off.  But otherwise, I cannot think why a router would separate the ACK and the payload?  I also think it would be odd for the client to fire off that ACK without waiting for payload when I would guess most protocols start with data from the client.  I agree re UDP, have been using for years, with no worries about SYN flood etc, because you can authenticate the first packet.  Crazy that TCP socket interface lets total strangers muck with your memory etc before you have any say in it.

Comment: My expectation that payload would be included on the client ACK was wrong, at least on OSX.  The payload does not go out until 3rd packet from client side.  This seems odd, given interest in TCP FastStart to avoid even the 3-way handshake.  I suppose there is some reason for it.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no in general, but Linux offers TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT socket option, which means accept() does not return until data has arrived.  In that case, read() immediately after accept() should return data.